# How to use spread operator?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React JS. I am trying to use spread operator here. Below is my code.

```
const parametersQuickStoreSearch = (searchTerms, options, store) => {
}
```

In the above code value of searchTerms is `simsKeycode:"35431081"` and value of store is `{value:all,label:all}`. I want to combine the value of searchTerms and store as below.

```
{ simsKeycode:"35431081", store: store.value }
```

I tried as below

```
const storeParam = {
    'store': store.value,
}
```

This line throwing me error `Unnecessarily quoted property 'store' found`
Can someone help me to complete this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the example :

```
const person = { name: 'David Walsh', gender: 'Male' };
const tools = { computer: 'Mac', editor: 'Atom' };

const summary = {...person, ...tools};
/*
Object {
  "computer": "Mac",
  "editor": "Atom",
  "gender": "Male",
  "name": "David Walsh",
}
*/
```

Comment: I have added const storeParam = {
    store: store.value,
  }; then  const newSearchTerms = {...searchTerms, ...storeParam}; but my newSearchTerms  has only value of searchTemrs

Answer (score 0):

You can try Object.assign

```
var searchTerms = {"simsKeycode":"35431081"}
var store = {"value":"all","label":"all"}
Object.assign({}, searchTerms, {store:store.value})
```

or spread operator

```
var searchTerms = {"simsKeycode":"35431081"}
var store = {"value":"all","label":"all"}
var storeParam = {store:store.value}
{...searchTerms, ...storeParam}
```

output:

```
"{"simsKeycode":"35431081","store":"all"}"
```

Comment: Thanks but my output should be { simsKeycode:"35431081", store: store.value }

Comment: In this case is the output  { simsKeycode:"35431081", store: "all" } ?